# HTML in code blocks treats # as a single-line comment

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting, markdown

Questions tagged with [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) (or that use the `<!-- language: lang-html -->` tag before code blocks) treat `#` as a single line comment for syntax highlighting like Python. To my knowledge, this is not how you denote a single line comment in HTML. It particularly becomes a problem in questions tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) in addition to [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) because it displays `id` selectors (which use `#`) as single line comments.

I understand that SO uses [Google Code Prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), but this seems like a bit of a large oversight if it is a problem with that service; does anyone use Prettify who can confirm that this is a service-wide issue?

Examples [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597905/fade-button-image-to-another-button-image) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597701/unable-to-get-button-level-with-text-box).

Comment: I think it does that with most languages (like CSS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTML tag don't use HTML-specific formatting by default. Because posts tagged [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) often have CSS, the generic syntax highlighter is used instead, because it produces half-decent results for both of them.

If you want to invoke the HTML-specific formatting, you need to specify...

`<!-- language: lang-html -->`

```html
<html>
# hello world
<b>hello</b>
```

Comment: That's interesting: quite a compromise. Almost defeats the purpose of having auto-syntax-highlighting if then you have to specify not only HTML but CSS as well if you want proper highlights. I guess it works for everything else, though...